# Handling async call inside onItemClick()

Tags: android, asynchronous, onitemclick

I have an implementation of onItemClick() while selecting from a list of items. However inside 
onItemClick() I need to perform a check via a library call that is async. Basically within onItemClick() a call to XYZ.checkConnection(booleanCallback); is made which is async.
And then in booleanCallback(int status) I can check for the status. What kind of pattern can I use  to handle this scenario?

Comment: A Little context plus code would help.if it is a UI related task that you want to perform on callback?

Comment: yes, once I get back the result from the async call, I need to perform a UI related task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Tester extends Activity {
private ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            new CheckConnection(list.getAdapter().getItem(position))
                    .execute();

        }
    });
}

private class CheckConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Object o;

    public CheckConnection(Object o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Do things like initiate progress bar etc
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do connection check
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        int status = 0;
        // determine status
        booleanCallBack(status, o);
    }
}

private void booleanCallBack(int status, Object o) {
    // perform UI related
}
}
```

you use the delegate approach if you want a modular class

I have essentially given you a starting point,this can be tweaked based on what you want.I didnt exactly get your context.hence the generalised answer